# FFMPEG "Segmentation fault" with network stream source

Tags: ffmpeg

I use release: 4.2.2 (static) from "https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/"

Final code will be on "Amazon AWS lambda"

Goal: use a url stream and add watermak

Link to video: ​https://feoval.fr/519.mp4

Link to Watermak: ​https://feoval.fr/watermark.png

```
./ffmpeg -i "https://feoval.fr/519.mp4" -i "./watermark.png" -filter_complex "overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10:format=rgb" -f "mp4" -movflags "frag_keyframe+empty_moov" -pix_fmt "yuv420p" test.mp4
```

return "Segmentation fault"

I have the same error on my computer and on AWS Lambda server

```
./ffmpeg -i "https://feoval.fr/519.mp4" -f "mp4" -movflags "frag_keyframe+empty_moov" -pix_fmt "yuv420p" test.mp4
```

work (but not watermak)

```
./ffmpeg -i "./519.mp4" -i "./watermark.png" -filter_complex "overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10:format=rgb" -f "mp4" -movflags "frag_keyframe+empty_moov" -pix_fmt "yuv420p" test.mp4
```

work (but not with stream)

Thanks you very much !

Logs for the first case who return "Segmentation fault":

```
...
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 (h264) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay (graph 0)
overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, ? for help
[libx264 @ 0x742e480] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
[libx264 @ 0x742e480] profile High, level 3.1, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x742e480] 264 - core 159 r2991 1771b55 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - ​http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=12 lookahead_threads=2 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
Metadata:
major_brand : mp42
minor_version : 1
compatible_brands: isommp41mp42
encoder : Lavf58.29.100
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 480x848, q=-1--1, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)
Metadata:
encoder : Lavc58.54.100 libx264
Side data:
cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
Metadata:
creation_time : 2020-01-13T08:54:26.000000Z
handler_name : Core Media Audio
encoder : Lavc58.54.100 aac
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to `readme.txt` that is packaged with the build from johnvansickle.com:

> A limitation of statically linking glibc is the loss of DNS
> resolution. Installing nscd through your package manager will fix
> this.

**Solution is to install and start the nscd service.**

Alternative solutions:

- Compile ([see tutorials](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide)) your own ffmpeg (during `./configure` enable gnutls, openssl, libtls or mbedtls for HTTPS support).
- Use ffmpeg from your repository
- Download the input file before using it in ffmpeg
- Use IP address instead of domain name