# Using FFmpeg with URL input causes SIGSEGV in AWS Lambda (Python runtime)

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, aws-lambda, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to implement a video converting solution on AWS Lambda following their article named [Processing user-generated content using AWS Lambda and FFmpeg](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/media/processing-user-generated-content-using-aws-lambda-and-ffmpeg/).
However when I run my command with `subprocess.Popen()` it returns `-11` which translates to SIGSEGV (segmentation fault).
I've tried to process the video with the newest (4.3.1) static build from [John Van Sickle](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/)'s site as with the "official" [ffmpeg-lambda-layer](https://serverlessrepo.aws.amazon.com/applications/arn:aws:serverlessrepo:us-east-1:145266761615:applications%7Effmpeg-lambda-layer) but it seems like it doesn't matter which one I use, the result is the same.

If I download the video to the Lambda's `/tmp` directory and add this downloaded file as an input to FFmpeg it works correctly (with the same parameters). However I'm trying to prevent this as the `/tmp` directory's max. size is only 512 MB which is not quite enough for me.

The relevant code which returns SIGSEGV:

```
ffmpeg_cmd = '/opt/bin/ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i "' + s3_source_signed_url + '" -i /opt/bin/audio.mp3 -i /opt/bin/watermark.png -shortest -y -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 4500k -c:a copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -filter_complex scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p -loglevel verbose -f flv -'
command1 = shlex.split(ffmpeg_cmd)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(command1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p1.communicate()
print(p1.returncode) #prints -11
```

stderr of FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3-static https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 20170516
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-debug --disable-ffplay --disable-indev=sndio --disable-outdev=sndio --cc=gcc-6 --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-gmp --enable-gray --enable-libaom --enable-libfribidi --enable-libass --enable-libvmaf --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librubberband --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-libzimg
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
[tcp @ 0x728cc00] Starting connection attempt to 52.219.74.177 port 443
[tcp @ 0x728cc00] Successfully connected to 52.219.74.177 port 443
[h264 @ 0x729b780] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuv420p
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com --> presigned url with 15 min expiration time':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    creation_time   : 2015-09-02T07:42:42.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:15.64, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2640 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, left), 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2475 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-02T07:42:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Video Handler
      encoder         : AVC Coding
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2015-09-02T07:42:42.000000Z
      handler_name    : L-SMASH Audio Handler
[mp3 @ 0x733f340] Skipping 0 bytes of junk at 1344.
Input #1, mp3, from '/opt/bin/audio.mp3':
  Metadata:
    encoded_by      : Logic Pro X
    date            : 2021-01-03
    coding_history  : 
    time_reference  : 158760000
    umid            : 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004500F9E4
    encoder         : Lavf58.49.100
  Duration: 00:04:01.21, start: 0.025057, bitrate: 320 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.97
Input #2, png_pipe, from '/opt/bin/watermark.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #2:0: Video: png, 1 reference frame, rgba(pc), 701x190 [SAR 1521:1521 DAR 701:190], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x7341140] w:1920 h:1080 flags:'bilinear' interl:0
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #2:0 (png) -> overlay:overlay
  format -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[h264 @ 0x72d8600] Reinit context to 1280x720, pix_fmt: yuv420p
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x733c1c0] w:1920 h:1080 flags:'bilinear' interl:0
[graph 0 input from stream 0:0 @ 0x7669200] w:1280 h:720 pixfmt:yuv420p tb:1/25 fr:25/1 sar:1/1 sws_param:flags=2
[graph 0 input from stream 2:0 @ 0x766a980] w:701 h:190 pixfmt:rgba tb:1/25 fr:25/1 sar:1521/1521 sws_param:flags=2
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x7670240] w:iw h:ih flags:'bilinear' interl:0
[deinterlace_in_2_0 @ 0x766b680] auto-inserting filter 'auto_scaler_0' between the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 2:0' and the filter 'deinterlace_in_2_0'
[Parsed_scale_0 @ 0x733c1c0] w:1280 h:720 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 -> w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv420p sar:1/1 flags:0x2
[Parsed_pad_1 @ 0x733ce00] w:1920 h:1080 -> w:1920 h:1080 x:0 y:0 color:0x000000FF
[Parsed_setsar_2 @ 0x733da00] w:1920 h:1080 sar:1/1 dar:16/9 -> sar:1/1 dar:16/9
[auto_scaler_0 @ 0x7670240] w:701 h:190 fmt:rgba sar:1521/1521 -> w:701 h:190 fmt:yuva420p sar:1/1 flags:0x2
[Parsed_overlay_3 @ 0x733e440] main w:1920 h:1080 fmt:yuv420p overlay w:701 h:190 fmt:yuva420p
[Parsed_overlay_3 @ 0x733e440] [framesync @ 0x733e5a8] Selected 1/50 time base
[Parsed_overlay_3 @ 0x733e440] [framesync @ 0x733e5a8] Sync level 2
[libx264 @ 0x72c1c00] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x72c1c00] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x72c1c00] profile Progressive High, level 4.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x72c1c00] 264 - core 157 r2969 d4099dd - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2019 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=2 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=0 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=9 lookahead_threads=3 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=1 keyint=60 keyint_min=6 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=10 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=4500 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'pipe:':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: mp42mp41isomavc1
    encoder         : Lavf58.20.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264), 1 reference frame ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 4500 kb/s, 30 fps, 1k tbn, 30 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.35.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/4500000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.97
frame=   27 fps=0.0 q=32.0 size=     247kB time=00:00:00.03 bitrate=59500.0kbits/s speed=0.0672x
frame=   77 fps= 77 q=27.0 size=    1115kB time=00:00:02.03 bitrate=4478.0kbits/s speed=2.03x
frame=  126 fps= 83 q=25.0 size=    2302kB time=00:00:04.00 bitrate=4712.4kbits/s speed=2.64x
frame=  177 fps= 87 q=26.0 size=    3576kB time=00:00:06.03 bitrate=4854.4kbits/s speed=2.97x
frame=  225 fps= 88 q=25.0 size=    4910kB time=00:00:07.96 bitrate=5047.8kbits/s speed=3.13x
frame=  272 fps= 89 q=27.0 size=    6189kB time=00:00:09.84 bitrate=5147.9kbits/s speed=3.22x
frame=  320 fps= 90 q=27.0 size=    7058kB time=00:00:11.78 bitrate=4907.5kbits/s speed=3.31x
frame=  372 fps= 91 q=26.0 size=    8098kB time=00:00:13.84 bitrate=4791.0kbits/s speed=3.4x
```

And that's the end of it. It should continue to do the processing until `00:04:02` as that's my audio's length but it stops here every time (approximately this is my video length).

The relevant code which works correctly:

```
ffmpeg_cmd = '/opt/bin/ffmpeg -stream_loop -1 -i "' + '/tmp/' + s3_source_key + '" -i /opt/bin/audio.mp3 -i /opt/bin/watermark.png -shortest -y -deinterlace -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset veryfast -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 4500k -c:a copy -map 0:v:0 -map 1:a:0 -filter_complex scale=1920:1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=1920:1080:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,setsar=1,overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2,format=yuv420p -loglevel verbose -f flv -'
command1 = shlex.split(ffmpeg_cmd)
p1 = subprocess.Popen(command1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
stdout, stderr = p1.communicate()
print(p1.returncode) #prints 0
```

With this code it repeats the video as many times as it has to do to be as long as the audio.

Both versions work correctly on my computer.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60528501/ffmpeg-segmentation-fault-with-network-stream-source) is almost the same but in my case FFmpeg is able to access the signed URL.

Comment: please post the `s3_source_signed_url`.

Comment: and maybe it SIGSEGV's because it hasn't enough space on the hard disk ?

Comment: What is the input video size and output video size? Because 512MB limit will be there

Comment: Did you test it without the `-shortest` flag?

Comment: What is the memory limit of your lambda? Is it possible that ffmpeg runs out of memory when it needs to keep the input video in RAM?